# How to write several commas in a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm converting a .txt file with annotations into another annotation format in a .csv file. The annotation format is as follows: `filepath,x1,y1,x2,y2,classname`. For pictures which haven't an instance of any class in them, annotation is like this: `filepath,,,,,`.

The problem is, that the `.writerrow` method of the `csv.writer` class doesn't write more than one comma after another.

My code is like this:

```
    with open(annotation_file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    
        splitted_lines = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
        
        with open(out_file, 'w', newline = '') as out:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(out,delimiter= ';' )
            for l in splitted_lines:
                if len(l) == 1:
                    # indicate empty images
                    csv_writer.writerow([l[0] + ',,,,,'])
```

l is a list that contains a single string, so by l[0] + ',,,,,' I want to concatenate l with five commas.

Thank you in advance

Comment: any particular reason for using csv, if not why not use json

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

set missing values as empty strings and fill the list

```py
with open(annotation_file, 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()
  splitted_lines = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]

with open(out_file, 'w', newline='') as out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=';')
    for l in splitted_lines:
        if len(l) == 1:
            # indicate empty images
            csv_writer.writerow(l + ['' for _ in range(5)])
        else:
            csv_writer.writerow(l)
```

Given sample data:

```py
data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [1],
]
```

it outputs:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6
1;2;3;4;5;6
1;2;3;4;5;6
1;;;;;
```

which is inline with what you want

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that l is a list which contains a string. When I apply your solution, the brackets of the list and the quotation marks of the string a written to the csv file. And this way doesn't add commas. I tried to just add five empty strings to my string, but no commas were written to the csv file.

Comment: I have confirmed that it works. if you want commas change delimiter to a comma `','`. maybe you should inspect the annotation file

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my problem, l is a string which contained a '\n' at the end. Because of this the writer wasn't able to write the five commas to the string. I changed the code like displayed below what fixed the problem.

```
    with open(annotation_file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    
        splitted_lines = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
        
        with open(out_file, 'w', newline = '') as out:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(out,delimiter= ';' )
            for l in splitted_lines:
                if len(l) == 1:
                    # indicate empty images
                    l[0] = l[0].replace('\n', '')
                    csv_writer.writerow([l[0] + ',,,,,'])
                else:
                    csv_writer.writerow(['something else'])
```

Thanks anyway @DelphiX

Comment: This really isn't the way to do it.  If you provide an example of your input file that includes the newline causing problems a more general solution can be provided.  The correct way to use `.writerow()` in this case is to always provide a list that is length 6.